# JMeter - get 401 response code for multiple users

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I'm setting up test plan using JMeter and using csv file for login data (2 data) and passing the token to another request using JSON extractor. 
I set up number of user in JMeter 10 users and the result is sometimes request get 401 code. I assume that maybe when user 1 login and create token for next request, then JMeter execute login request with same data so change the token.
Can someone help me to fix the issue ?

[JMeter picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eThUc.png)

Comment: It is happening sometimes. At that instance, either credentials are wrong or dynamic token is not changed or correlation issue. Try with 1 user and then with 2 and further to dig the problem. I know it is not the answer but with limited information it is hard to tell as it is happening sometimes. Meanwhile, some expert might give some more good inputs.

Comment: Hi @sunny_teo thank you for the response, I tried that before, it still get 401 code sometimes, and when I use that for large number of users, more than 90% request get 401 code too.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the token value with the help Regular expression and passed it in the next request.

Comment: Thank you for response. I Using JSON extractor and passed it with HTTP header manager, it doesn't effective ?

Comment: Hi, Can you send me JSON response? and which value you want to extract. I will share the exact expression.

Comment: Hi, this is JSON response. https://i.stack.imgur.com/MO1MF.png
I can extract and passed token value to another response, but when I execute that with blazemeter and large number of users, more than 90% the request failed.

Comment: Hi, If the parameterization  is correct then add constant timer in between ever request.

Comment: Hi, I set it to 700 ms before, is it enough ? because I set it and I still get same problem :(

Comment: Hi, I am not sure but you can start from 3000 ms. One more setting you can do. Go to test plan - Checked "Run Thread Groups consecutively ". May this setting works for you.

Comment: Hi, I still get 401 code, most of them get 401 code, sir.
May I know, It is usually happen in load testing sir ?

Comment: Hi, No it does not happen. Try open browser - console - Network and login manually with those user and see the response. If you get same error then users have issue.